# How can I implement a function, which is specified with an "extern" clause in a C header, within a C++ class?

Tags: c++, static-methods, extern

I'm gonna use a driver library implemented in C in my project written in C++. The library's [header file](https://github.com/ElektorLabs/ads1115-driver/blob/master/ads1x1x.h) contains a number of [function stubs declared as *extern*](https://github.com/ElektorLabs/ads1115-driver/blob/master/ads1x1x.h#L27) I will have to implement:

```c
extern uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write (uint8_t i2c_address);
```

My C++ code now contains a class named `vfd`, which will contain static methods implmenting the respective function stubs, just like this:

```cpp
uint8_t vfd::ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write (uint8_t i2c_address) {
  uint8_t ret = 0x00;
  // do something
  return ret;
}
```

In the header file of the `vfd` class, the corresponding lines will look like this:

```cpp
class vfd {
  public:
    uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write (uint8_t i2c_address);
}
```

How shall I declare my methods so that the compiler will recognise them as implementations of the respective `extern` functions from my library header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You can implement these C functions in your C++ file separately and make them call your static functions inside the class:

```cpp
extern "C" uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write (uint8_t i2c_address) {
    vfd::ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write(address);
}
```

They're static, right? Otherwise you also have to provide a `this` object for the method to call on, and it's nowhere in C API, you will have to figure it out yourself, e.g.:

```cpp
extern "C" uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write (uint8_t i2c_address) {
    some_var_of_type_vfd.ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write(address);
}
```

Comment: Will I have to refer to these extern "C" functions in the header file `vfd.h`, too?

Answer (score 7):

> How shall I declare my methods so that the compiler will recognise them as implementations of the respective extern functions from my library header?

You cannot do that. An `extern "C"` is not the same as a `static` member function of a class.

You can implement the `extern "C"` function such that it is a pass through to the `static` member function of the class.

```
extern "C" uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write (uint8_t i2c_address)
{
    return vfd::ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write(i2c_address);
}
```